# Difference between the two autodifficulty commands in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to know the difference between the two bots autodifficulty commands -

`bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low`

`bot_autodifficulty_threshold_high`

Are they min. and max value of difficulty scaling range?

Comment: welcome to arqade =) I feel this is in part a very good question. I am removing the parts asking why the game includes 2 AIs and why they could not do just 1. The short answer is "because the developers made it that way", but we dont take questions that concern development.

Comment: Thanks, and no problem with the edit. The developers made it that way, then they must be having different meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Valve developer community](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Custom_Game_Mode) you can see that **bot_autodifficulty_threshold_high**    corresponds with the amount above avg human contribution score, above which a bot should lower its difficulty.

**bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low** corresponds with the amount below avg human contribution score, below which a bot should raise its difficulty.